# W/ClassMapper: No setter/field when using FirebaseListAdapter in Java

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to build a simple chat app. I'm very new to Firebase. The structure of the database is this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Chat");
    firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Room>(this, Room.class, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, databaseReference) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, Room room, int position) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            String roomName = this.getRef(position).getKey();
            textView.setText(roomName);
        }
    };
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(firebaseListAdapter);
```

Here is my Room class:

```
    class Room {
    private String room;

    public Room() {}

    public Room(String room) {this.room = room;}

    public void setRoom(String room) {this.room = room;}
    public String getRoom() {return room;}
}
```

When I try to populate the listview, the items are correctly displayed, but although I have set the getters and the setters, every time I start the activity, I get this error for 12 times:

```
W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -KZcHa8wYpcvLSb7atX- found on class example.com.chat.Room
```

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you show the whole database structure?

Comment: Yes. It's a very simple one. I changed it right now. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I meant the inside of /Chat/Room3/-KZcHa8wYpcvLSb7atX/

Comment: Your `Room` class does not represent the inside of each `Chat`'s child. But it looks like you just want to get the `Room`'s key, you can safely ignore that warning. That warning will not crash your app.

Comment: Ok, i understant that is no problem with this but is there a way to get rid of this warning? Or is there a way in which i can change the Room class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using that database structure, you can't get rid of those warnings because `FirebaseListAdapter` automatically trying to parse the response from firebase to an object class.

You have 2 options:

- Change the database structure
- Don't use `FirebaseListAdapter`, use `ChildEventListener` instead and then add the value manually to the `ListView`

If you want to change the database structure, you can change it to this

```
 {
    "Chat": {
        "Room1": {
            ...
        },
        "Room2": {
            ...
        },
        "Room3": {
            ...
        }
    },
    "Chat_Rooms": {
        "Room1": true,
        "Room2": true,
        "Room3": true
    }
}
```

then reference the `DatabaseReference` to "Chat_Rooms"

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Chat_Rooms");
firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Boolean>(this, Boolean.class, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, databaseReference) {
    @Override
    protected void populateView(View v, Boolean value, int position) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        String roomName = this.getRef(position).getKey();
        textView.setText(roomName);
    }
};
```

Comment: Before this, i used `ChildEventListener` and it worked fine but in my case, i'm using `FirebaseListAdapter` and the the change of the database structure was the answer. Thanks!